# Does mysqlhotcopy  block SELECT statements from different clients?

Tags: mysql, backup, select, mysqlhotcopy

I would like to create a backup of different MyISAM tables on a server using mysqlhotcopy. These tables are about 6GB in size. I would like to know, does mysqlhotcopy block users from SELECTing (reading) data from the tables while taking the backup?

Thanks in advance, Tim

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is not as clear as it should be, but I would say no, mysqlhotcopy does not block SELECT queries.

Here is why

### **REASON #1 : MySQL Docs on ['mysqlhotcopy'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlhotcopy.html)**

> mysqlhotcopy is a Perl script that was originally written and
> contributed by Tim Bunce. It uses FLUSH TABLES, LOCK TABLES, and cp or
> scp to make a database backup. It is a fast way to make a backup of
> the database or single tables, but it can be run only on the same
> machine where the database directories are located. mysqlhotcopy works
> only for backing up MyISAM and ARCHIVE tables. It runs on Unix and
> NetWare.
>
> To use mysqlhotcopy, you must have read access to the files for the
> tables that you are backing up, the SELECT privilege for those tables,
> the RELOAD privilege (to be able to execute FLUSH TABLES), and the
> LOCK TABLES privilege (to be able to lock the tables).

### **REASON #2 : MySQL Docs on ['Lock Tables' Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html)**

> • If you are using tables for a nontransactional storage engine, you
> must use LOCK TABLES if you want to ensure that no other session
> modifies the tables between a SELECT and an UPDATE. The example shown
> here requires LOCK TABLES to execute safely:  LOCK TABLES trans READ,
> customer WRITE; SELECT SUM(value) FROM trans WHERE
> customer_id=some_id; UPDATE customer   SET
> total_value=sum_from_previous_statement   WHERE customer_id=some_id;
> UNLOCK TABLES;   Without LOCK TABLES, it is possible that another
> session might insert a new row in the trans table between execution of
> the SELECT and UPDATE statements.

In summary, since mysqlhotcopy launches `LOCK TABLES`, `SELECT` queries are evidently still allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I you definitely don't want to block the user from any action, set up a replication slave. You can hotcopy those tables without impacting on the end user.